# How do I convert datetime.timedelta to integer months?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

Hopefully this is a simple fix, I've searched around on here to find a similar question and can't find something that deals with this specific issue. If it does exist the answers flew right over my head...

I have a list of start and end dates and I want to find the difference between them, in months, and then use that value to calculate something else. Here are the start and end dates:

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 | 2022-09-01 |
| 2022-10-30 | 2023-03-30 |
| 2022-10-30 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2022-05-01 | 2023-03-30 |
| 2021-05-02 | 2023-03-30 |
| 2022-10-30 | 2023-09-01 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023-09-30 |

In the past I have done it like this:

`(df1['End Date'] - df1['Start Date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')`

and indeed when I run it, it returns:

```
0    16.033183
1     4.961087
2    14.029036
3    10.940676
4    22.899854
5    10.053595
6    11.959178
dtype: float64
```

Now I would like to do this in a for loop because there are rows in my data that I don't want this calculation to apply to. When I run it in a loop I get this error:

```
`UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[M]')`
```

I have tried to break it down. If I run this

```
`print((df1['End Date'].iloc[2] - df1['Start Date'].iloc[2]))`
```

I get this,

```
`427 days, 0:00:00`
```

but if I run this,

```
`print((df1['End Date'].iloc[2] - df1['Start Date'].iloc[2])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))`
```

I get the same error as above.

So I can see why an error is appearing, I think, but I don't know what to do about it. I've tried converting the date difference like this,

```
`(df1['End Date'].iloc[2] - df1['Start Date'].iloc[2]).astype("timedelta64")`
```

but it errors saying,

```
`AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'astype'`
```

So yeah. Now I'm stuck. I suppose I could add a column with the date difference and then use that onward for what I need, but I'd like to understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: "*I would like to do this in a for loop because there are rows in my data that I don't want this calculation to apply to.*" - sounds like XY to me - what is it you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "sounds like XY"

Not all rows have a date diff of >12 months. So for the rows where the start and end dates fall between a specific range and have a difference of over 12 months, I want to find the total number of months and then calculate what 12 months worth would equate to.

Comment: This means that "*Now I would like to do this in a for loop*" and "*because there are rows in my data that I don't want this calculation to apply to*" don't go well together. It's as if someone asked you "*have you seen the chainsaw? I can't open this bottle*" you immediately feel that they probably won't do the *right* thing. Care to explain what is your real issue with enough detail?

Comment: At this point I'd just like to understand why 
`(df1['End Date'] - df1['Start Date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')`
does what I want but,
`(df1['End Date'].iloc[2] - df1['Start Date'].iloc[2])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')`
doesn't

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? (as code to generate the DataFrame with the exact dtypes)

Comment: sorry for not clarifying what I meant by "XY" ! Thanks @mozway for the nice illustration. Opening a beer with a chainsaw sounds pretty cool btw. :)

Comment: @FObersteiner apparently, [it's a thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZ-slvv_ZT4&t=27) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could try this:

```
(df1['End Date'].dt.to_period('M') - df1['Start Date'].dt.to_period('M'))
```